# Issue with "Multiple methods named...."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, popup

I got a probelm. I would like to implement the UAModalpanelview to my project. At first it worked fine...I implemented the files...whatever. But now I would like to run the application, but I got this error every time. It is because of the "center" it shows me that "Mutliple methods named center found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes".

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender {

    UAModalPanel *modalPanel = [[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:modalPanel];
    [modalPanel showFromPoint:[sender center]];
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to cast sender to an object type.  I would assume it is a UIView.

```
[modalPanel showFromPoint:[(UIView *)sender center]];
```

You can take a look at this similar question:  [Why am I am getting the warning "Multiple methods named 'center' found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129778/why-am-i-am-getting-the-warning-multiple-methods-named-center-found)